# Can't enable port forwarding due to No base MAC address error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to enable port-forwarding so i can access my vagrant box from my local machine, but whenever i run my vagrant box i get this error,

```
No base MAC address was specified. This is required for the NAT networking
to work properly (and hence port forwarding, SSH, etc.). Specifying this
MAC address is typically up to the box and box maintainer. Please contact
the relevant person to solve this issue.
```

But when I re-run `vagrant up` command, it works just fine except that I can't ping it from my host machine.

I am using the following line in my `Vagrantfile` to enable port forwarding,

```
   config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
```

and I am trying to ping it in my host machine as follows,

```
ping 127.0.0.1:4567
```

Can someone please tell me how can I fix this mac error issue so that I can ping and access my box from my local machine ?

EDIT:
I have tried this code to set the MAC address but its not doing anything either.

```
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--macaddress1", "auto"]
  end
```